Is there a maximum number of time driven triggers that can run across multiple files in Google Apps Script?
I have three identical functions set up in two separate files, each targeting different sheets within my spreadsheet. I set up time-driven triggers for each function. One file runs these triggers perfectly, while the other only works when triggered manually. Is there a limit to the number of time-driven triggers that can function simultaneously

I tried deleting and re-creating the trigger
Changing the timing of the trigger


According to this documentation the maximum number of time-driven triggers that can be created in a Google Apps Script project is 20 per user, per script. This limit applies to all types of time-driven triggers, including triggers set up for different sheets within a spreadsheet. You might have different triggers set up from different spreadsheets you have.

Ah that's odd, I only have 6 triggers set up across all sheets. Thanks for doc, I'll dig into it  :)

The time-based trigger didn't work because I used getActiveSheet() which should really only be used when there is a spreadsheet with one sheet. This method gets the sheet that is being displayed in the UI; since I had multiple sheets, the trigger only worked for the "active sheet".
I changed getActiveSheet to getSheetByName("") and it worked.

Get active sheet has no real meaning when there is no user so you need to be careful with triggers that can be running when there is no user present.
